# Euler parameterization definition.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am given a parameterization $\vec{\gamma}(t) = \langle a \cos t, b \sin t \rangle$ of the ellipse $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

I am now asked to write this in terms of an Euler parameterization.

I can not find the definition of an Euler parameterization anywhere. Can somebody explain to me what is meant by this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this means that you have to find a parametrization of the form
$$
\varphi(t) = r(t)\binom{\cos t}{\sin t}.
$$

Comment: What is $r(t)$?

Comment: Sorry. $r(t)$ should be a non-negative number for each $t$. It is the distance to zero of the point on the ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Identify $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$, that is, write $$\gamma(t) = a\cos t + i b\sin t,$$and try to put that in the form $\gamma(t) = r(t) e^{i\theta(t)}$. This seems tricky, though. We can compute at once $$r(t) = \|\gamma(t)\| = \sqrt{a^2\cos^2t + b^2 \sin^2t}.$$ For the argument, use $\cos(\theta(t)) = {\rm Re}(\gamma(t))/\|\gamma(t)\|$ and $\sin( \theta(t)) = {\rm Im}(\gamma(t))/\|\gamma(t)\|$ (it won't look pretty).